# Visualforce pageBlockSection Column/Header Limitation

Tags: visualforce, pageblocksection

I am recreating a form made in Excel over in Salesforce. I have run into a speed bump with VF pageBlockSection.

VF page as it looks now:
[image]

Goal:
[image]

How do I change columns within a pageBlockSection without having to create another pageBlockSection. Specifically, how may I remove the empty header?

VF Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Prospect_Profile__c">
<apex:pageBlock title="Prospect Profile">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cName" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.name}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cDescription_of_Business__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Description_of_Business__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cKey_Decision_Makers__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Key_Decision_Makers__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cIndustry__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Industry__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cAssociated_Entities__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Associated_Entities__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="" columns="2">
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cLaw_Firm__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Law_Firm__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cLaw_Firm_Contact__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Law_Firm_Contact__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<apex:page standardController="Prospect_Profile__c">
<apex:pageBlock title="Prospect Profile">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information" columns="1">
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cName" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.name}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cDescription_of_Business__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Description_of_Business__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cKey_Decision_Makers__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Key_Decision_Makers__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cIndustry__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Industry__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cAssociated_Entities__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Associated_Entities__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cLaw_Firm__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Law_Firm__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="Prospect_Profile__cLaw_Firm_Contact__c" value="{!Prospect_Profile__c.Law_Firm_Contact__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

just remove tittle="" from that pageblock section

Comment: Your a boss, should of tried that before I reached out! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, Please mark this as an answer .